# Problems parsing XML from a String but not a file

Tags: java, android, xml, inputstream

I have an xml parser that works perfectly when I load it from a file:

```
private void getParsedXML(int id, Context context) throws Exception {
        /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader */
        XMLHandlerLevel myExampleHandler = new XMLHandlerLevel();
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);
        /* Load xml file from raw folder*/
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(id); 

        /* Begin parsing */
        xr.parse(new InputSource(in));
        this.levelData = myExampleHandler.getLevelData();
        in.close();
    }
```

But now I also get somme content form a server. The XML is then send as a String and this is where it blocks:

```
private void getParsedXML(String s) throws Exception{
        if(this.levelData == null){
            InputStream in = StringToStream(s);
            /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLHandlerLevel myExampleHandler = new XMLHandlerLevel();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            /* Begin parsing */
            xr.parse(new InputSource(in));



            this.levelData = myExampleHandler.getLevelData();
            Log.e("jason",(levelData!=null)?levelData.toString():null);
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

and here is the StringToString Function

```
    public static InputStream StringToStream(String text) {
            InputStream is = null;
            /*
             * Convert String to InputStream using ByteArrayInputStream 
             * class. This class constructor takes the string byte array 
             * which can be done by calling the getBytes() method.
             */
            try {
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                 is.reset();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("jason","failed again");
            }
            return is;
        }
```

But this doesn't work...

I am sure of the content of the String.
and I tested the StringToStream function it works fine.

I also put logs in XMLHandlerLevel to check what was happening and NOTHING the function startDocument() isn't even called but I get no error message no exceptions so I'm completely lost to explain this.

to resume:
**My XMLParser works fine when the Stream comes from context.getResources().openRawResource(id); 
but not when it comes form a String
Why?**

Thanks for any ideas

Jason

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: You dont have the make the text into an InputStream, a StringReader would be better. But the pasrsing code is essentially the same - there must be something else wrong? In cases like this, make the parse method take in the xml source in such a way that the working and - non-working code share some logic, so that you can eliminitate the shared code as a problem..

Comment: @kgiannakakis there is no Exception Thrown that is what is annoying me the most. @Thomas tis already what I've done  the only differences is the creation on the InputSource

Comment: You don't appear to be setting the ContentHandler in the code path that takes a String (see my updated answer).

Comment: @Blaise Doughan: thanks ! I can't belive how blind I was on this one :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't appear to be setting a content handler in the code path that takes a string.

Why not wrap the String in a StringReader and parse that instead?

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(string));
xr.parse(is);
```

You example (modified):

```
private void getParsedXML(String s) throws Exception{
    if(this.levelData == null){
        /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLHandlerLevel myExampleHandler = new XMLHandlerLevel();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        /* Begin parsing */
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(string));
        xr.parse(is);

        this.levelData = myExampleHandler.getLevelData();
        Log.e("jason",(levelData!=null)?levelData.toString():null);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure that it will help u but there is a external jar file called Jsoup.jar add it to your project, it have the APIs of parsing xml,html...see tutorial on internet....